# Install Xcode without admin

Tags: mac, xcode, command-line, development

Is there any way to use Xcode on a computer that I don't have admin permissions for?

Is there a way to at least use command line tools like git and gcc?

Comment: Is this your computer?

Comment: It's my parents computer. I have a laptop but I want to use theirs for programming and they don't want me to have their password :/

Comment: then I think you have some negotiating to do;) No, it's not possible, otherwise, there's no security. You can install, get them to enter the password when asked. still won't get you anywhere if you need sudo or admin perms from inside the tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an answer to this over on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837889/authorize-a-non-admin-developer-in-xcode-mac-os

> You need to add your OS X user name to the _developer group. See the [posts in this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2654321)* for more information. The following command should do the trick:
>
> ```
> sudo dscl . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership <username>
> ```

It looks like you'll still need the admin account for this part but after that you should be able to run Xcode on your account.

*This isn't the link from the original answer. That page is actually gone. I've added a new link ot a thread in the Apple Support Communities.

Hat tip to Ned Deily.